# When to use $\implies$ or $\iff$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Whenever writing a solution for a equation when you go on to the next step what sign to use $ \implies $ or$ \iff$ like

$\textbf{Scenario 1}$

$x^2=36 \implies x= \pm 6$

$\textbf{Scenario 2}$

$x^2 =36 \iff x= \pm 6$

And when writing a solution in continuation which sign to use or are both of them alright?

Comment: If you can "reverse" the inference, then 2 is correct (as in the case above). But in e.g. $x > 0 \Rightarrow x \ge 0$ we cannot.

Comment: $((A\implies B) \land (B\implies A)) \iff (A \iff B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example both are correct and useful, but there are examples where one direction is not that useful, like in this example:

$$(x+3)^3 < 27$$
$$ \implies x^3 < 27$$
$$ \iff x<3$$

[The first transition is simply explained by $x^3 \leq (x+3)^3$]

The above is correct and gives a partial solution to the problem, but not the full solution, as you can see from this other calculation:

$$(x+3)^3 < 27$$
$$ \iff x+3 < 3$$
$$ \iff x<0$$

This gives you a more complete solution to your equation.

Answer (score 1):

In scenario 1, use the implication symbol $\implies$ to indicate that the solution follows from the previous step. In scenario 2, use the biconditional symbol $\iff$ to indicate that the equation is true if and only if the solution holds. Both symbols can be used in continuation, depending on the logical connection between the steps.